# How to force inline-block divs to stretch to highest one via CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs that one of them is shown higher on a tablet browser because the text inside it stretches it extra one line, so how can I force the other two divs to stretch to same its height? I don't want to use the JavaScript, just the CSS and prefer CSS3 to be compatible with old browsers like IE7.

```
<div id="box1" style="display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;margin:12px;vertical-align:top">
       <!-- Longer text here-->
</div>

<div id="box2" style="display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;margin:12px;vertical-align:top">
     <!-- Short text here -->  
</div>

<div id="box3" style="display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;margin:12px;vertical-align:top">
     <!-- Short text here -->   
</div>
```

Note: I don't use the table because I have a responsive design.

Comment: Put them all inside a `<div>` and set all their heights to `auto`? Your existing code is a bit messy anyhow; I recommend not using inline style - instead move the CSS to a dedicated block.

Comment: Thanks, the inline style and the zoom:1 is for IE7, it has nothing to do with other browsers.

Comment: You've ruled out all the possible CSS options by requiring IE7 support *except* using an actual `table`. You will need javascript....but **seriously** IE7?